# How to interact with unfocused/alt tabbed chrome window/tab

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have this application that listens to certain key inputs, like the spacebar being pressed and than it performs an action. And I want to know if it's possible to input the spacebar press while I have a full screen game focused.
This is my code:

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <input type="text" class="keyboard" />
    </div>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () 
        {
            function tts ()
            {
                var msg = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance('Hello World!');
                msg.volume = .75;
                window.speechSynthesis.speak(msg);
            }
    
            const keyBoard = document.querySelector('.keyboard')
            keyBoard.addEventListener('keyup', e =>
            {
                console.log(e)
                if(e.keyCode == 52)
                {
                    tts()
                }
            })

        });
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: No. Keyboard event capturing does not work when the tab/document is not in focus.

Comment: This is not possible. This would be terribly bad for security: imagine any website you open being able to capture what you type in other apps/websites…

Comment: Yeah, you guys are right, would that be possible with c#?